# How can I change a defunct Apple ID email address?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, email, apple-id

I never changed my student email account to which all app purchases have been made. I just upgraded to iOS 5, and it requires to authenticate the iCloud, by verifying an email sent to the now defunct email address. The problem is that I can't even change my email adress, because the system wants to verify my iCloud account first. It's a circular problem!

Can't change email because I haven't verified iCloud, and I can't verify iCloud because my old email is now defunct.

What can I do??

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could try addressing the problem from the other side of the issue.  When I faced a similar problem with my now defunct student email address on another account, the solution turned out to be contacting the IT department of my old school and convincing them to temporarily re-instate my student email address.  Once I convinced them to do it, it turned out to be a really simple process.  I was able to change over and recover passwords from several services tied to the old email address, and once completed just had them deactivate it again.  Your milage may vary depending on your educational institution, but it's definitely worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use https://appleid.apple.com/ which allows you to change Apple ID details:

[image]

Select "Manage your account" and use your existing Apple ID and password to log in.

[image]

Choose the option to edit your Apple ID/Primary Email Address:

[image]

and enter a new one.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work because I first need to verify my apple ID via email, and my email no-longer works. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I assume you still know your password? Once you've logged in (via 'Manage your account'), can't you change your primary email/apple ID (by clicking 'Edit' at the end of the displayed address) without needing to verify the old one?

Comment: When I go to this site, the Edit link is missing after primary email address.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried going to https://iforgot.apple.com/? You should be able to change your Apple ID to an existing email address and subsequently sign up for iCloud.

Comment: I can't verify my even Apple ID, because its attached to an old email address. and I can't change the address, until I have verified via email my apple id.