# changing email of account to an already used email

Tags: accounts

I have an old apple account with my actual email that I don't use anymore.  I don't care about the data on that account.

I have my current account which uses an email I can no longer access.  I want to change it to use my old email, but can't since its associated with the other account.

Can I delete the old account in such a way that I'll be able to set that past email as the email of my current apple account?

Comment: What do you mean by apple account - I have 4 different ones with 2 different login emails covering them

Comment: The account used to log into the apple store and things like that.

Comment: Ah that is a fifth possibly - the ones I had were  to Mac App Store , another to iTunes/iOS App Store = the others IO have are Apple developer account and iCloud. I need to work what login is for Apple Store

Comment: Looking at the Apple Store app my login is the same as for IOS app store

Comment: So the question I think is what exactly are you buying? Music, ITunes downloads, iOs apps, Mac apps or hardware?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/how-can-i-change-a-defunct-apple-id-email-address